# How to simulate a simple equation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have this equation that I need to simulate and then plot Y in terms of X. I use the following code to do this but at the end it gives me this straight line as the graph which clearly isn't what I expect to see:

```
r = .5;
beta = 5;
b = 1;
N = 10;
K = 15;
p = .7:.05:5.7;
l_0 = 0:.01:1;

p*K.*(1-(l_0/r)) == 1./((N*beta*(b^beta)./((beta-1)*l_0))).^(1/(beta-1));

plot(p,l_0,'b*-')
```

I need to see how l_0 varies as p varies by simulating the equation and using the parameter values above.

This is the graph that I get when I run the code:
[image]

I somehow guess that there's something wrong with the way I've set the values for p and l_0 but I'm almost new to MATLAB and don't know how to fix it. I'd appreciate if any one could help me to find out where I'm making mistake(s).

Comment: The line that contains `==` computes two expressions, compares them, and the result of the comparison is ignored, because it is not assigned to anything. I think you need to solve the equality for the y variable (`l_0`) manually, then compute its value and plot it. Or maybe you’re supposed to use the symbolic toolbox with `solve`. Ask your instructor if in doubt!

Comment: But the kind of plot that you like to see is a surface plot right ? In order to cover the whole `[l_0,p]` space

Comment: Are there any leads on this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you view the MATLAB Documents page for the [colon operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html), you will see that `:` acts as a unit vector. Basically, it creates a linear space from j to k, by i intervals. So the graph as it is currently displayed is correct. It displays two linear vectors.

However, what you may want to change is the aspect ratio of the graph. Right now, your aspect ratio custom fits your data (which it sounds like you do not want). Look under the `axis style` section in the MATLAB Documentation for [axis limits and aspect ratios](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) to see what style you want your plot in.

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

The graph/plot that you are showing here is seems to work only with this:

```
p = .7:.05:5.7;
l_0 = 0:.01:1;

plot(p,l_0,'b*-')
```

YES! that is it. All the other things that you have written are playing no role (it seems).

basically you have not evaluated / populated `p` with `l_0` so if you want to see that then

- keep `p` blank
- Rearrange your equation with only `p` at LHS.
- Let `l_0` handle/fill the values of `p`.

Now if you only want to see the curve/plot between `p = .7:.05:5.7;`, then you can check how to do that with the axes property or simply zoom-in/out.

Hope this helps

Comment: Rearrangement might look like this `p == 1./K.*(1-(l_0/r))*((N*beta*(b^beta)./((beta-1)*l_0))).^(1/(beta-1));`

Comment: ...but with a single equal sign. I interpreted OP’s problem to need to compute `l_0` from `p`, but with the poor description it is not possible to tell.

Comment: Ohh my bad, Yes single equal sign

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, that is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Saba is it any better than before?